# finding the period of $\sin(2x+3)$

Tags: calculus, functions, periodic-functions

I tried to find the period of $\sin(2x+3)$;

looking for $p>0$ such that $ \sin(2(x+p)+3)=\sin(2x+3),$ for all $ x \in R$

which means:  $ \sin(2(x+p)+3)  - \sin(2x+3)= 0 ,$ for all $ x \in R$

that is $\sin(p)\cdot \cos(2x+3+p)=0$, for all $ x \in R$

I'm not sure how to continue....

Comment: Translations does not change the period, then the period of $\sin(2x+3)$ is the same of $\sin(2x)$.

Comment: $\sin p=0$, that is $p=\pi$, if you want the smallest positive period.

Comment: Like DiegoMath said, the period isn't affected by translations. The period of the usual sine function is $2\pi$ and here it is twice as frequent thus, you can conclude...

Comment: I would like to know how to finish said calculation

Comment: Since I am, as one can see trying to calculate it instead of deduce it

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(2x+3)=\sin\left(2\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$

The period is $$p=\frac{2\pi}{2}=\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

last equation implies 
$cos(2x+3+p)=0$ for all $ x\in R$ which is not possible as it is function of $ x$

other solution is $\sin p=0$ for all $x\in R$ which implies $p=n\pi$ where $n \in I$ and $\neq 0$(which would result in $\sin(2x+3)=\sin(2x+3)$

hence smallest period is when $n=1$,ie.$p=\pi$

Comment: another assumption can be that if the first option were to be true you would have a p which changes as x changes thus not a constant which is exactly what we do not want.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function
A function f is said to be periodic with period $P$ ($P$ being a nonzero constant) if we have
$f(x+P) = f(x) $
for all values of $x$ in the domain

Comment: Yeah I read that as matter of fact already...a pity it's only definition

Comment: P should be constant